# Get Maven to run Javadoc:javadoc from mvn package

Tags: java, maven, configuration

I have configure javadoc i Maven, but i have to execute  **mvn javadoc:javadoc**
i like Maven to to this while i execute **mvn package**.

My pom look like

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <aggregate>true</aggregate>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>package</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin configuration shows that the javadoc plugin is called in the phase prepare-package. Thus, if you call `mvn package` this plugin is executed. But the javadoc plugin has no goal package: [see plugin info here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/plugin-info.html).

I think you want to call the javadoc goal:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
                ...
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-javadoc</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>javadoc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```